# Need to enable UITextField in row of UITableView when cell is selected in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have created a custom cell that places a UITextField in each row of a UITableView.  What I would like to do is enable the UITextField for a particular row (i.e. activate the cursor in that textfield), when the user presses on anywhere inside the cell.

I have the following method where I try to do this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     [_cell.textField setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

}
```

However, this is not working.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track placing this inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. However, setting user interaction enabled on the textfield just means that the user would be allowed to interact with the object if they tried. You're looking for becomeFirstResponder.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: What if I have multiple text fields in a row and want to detect which one was closest to the user touch?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     [_cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is this `_cell` iVar? Are you setting it somewhere?

I think what you are trying to accomplish is this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Notice that in this way you are getting the cell for the tapped indexPath.

And also, just for information, it's a pattern in objective-C to use booleans as `YES` or `NO`, instead of `true` or `false`.